# Best way for block SQL table records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL Table in SQL Server like this:

[image: Table]

In this table there are old records (Last year).
I should use this table again.But old records to be blocked (No operation taken on them (Select,Update, Delete)).

I can't modify design table and add another field like `locked` or `date` or add new table for handle operations.

Is this possible in SQL Server?

It would be very helpful if someone could explain best solution for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably have an application on top of your database. Make the lock in that layer.

Comment: Is your ID column have identity property

Comment: @StackUser Yes ID have identity property. But I do not want to use last ID for this solution.

Comment: How do you find last year old records without date or max(ID) column

Comment: @StackUser I don't need to find old records. Now, all of records are old records.

Comment: Based on your requirements, you need to archive these off into a different table, and possible delete or archive any related records in other tables that have a foreign key relationship. _or_ you could create another separate table that attaches a year to an ID (you'll need to do this next year as well right?) and utilise that. But these are all hacks. I suggest you explain in a bit more detail what you are trying to do. Since you can't edit this table I guess you can't create another or delete records

Comment: if you insert new records than how can you now which is old records and which are new records ?

Comment: @GuidoG If old records to be blocked, I can divide records in two partitions (blocked,unblocked). New records are unblock records.

Comment: yes but how do you do that ? do you have a column for that or what ?

Comment: @GuidoG This is exactly my question that without adding new column, I would categorize records.

Comment: without adding new column all you can do is create new table and store all the ID's of old records there. Than you can create triggers on your table that block update/delete if the ID exists in the new table

Comment: @GuidoG I know many ways to do this, but I need to manage this work without add new column or new table.This may not be possible in SQL Server.

Comment: than all you can do is write down the current min and max ID and use them in update/delete trigger and block if the ID is in that range. Its dirty but if you cannot create column and not even a table than you have no other options. Why cannot you create new table ?

Comment: Check these urls: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188730.aspx and https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2888/how-to-partition-an-existing-sql-server-table/

Comment: @GuidoG add new column or new table is need to getting new permission from the customer. This is very hard!

Comment: so tell your customer that you cannot make changes without permission to make changes.

Comment: You need to store some information. It makes sense to store that info in the same database. There is no way you can avoid having to create or change something in the database. I suspect there is more to this story and there is probably a better solution